# Why does $x return items outside of the context?

Tags: html, xpath, codeception

I am attempting to use an xpath locator within a context for a Codeception test using the Selenium driver with Firefox. Specifically, I am trying to click the second link in the message body of an email, viewed with roundcube.

The body of the email is in the div with xpath `//div[@class="rcmBody"]`

I can get the link with this path: `(//div[@class="rcmBody"]//a)[2]`

But for some reason when I try `//a[2]` within the context of the body div, it returns all `a` elements within the iframe.

An example from codeception: (after selecting the correct iframe)

```
$I->click('//a[2]', '//div[@class="rcmBody"]')
```

This causes the web driver to click the second link in the iframe which comes before the body div begins.

I can also test this from directly in chrome:

```
$x('//a', $x('//div[@class="rcmBody"]')[0])
```

This returns a list of all `a` elements within the iframe, not within the context.

How can I get the context part to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dot to the beginning of XPath to make it *context-specific*:

```
$I->click('(.//a)[2]', '//div[@class="rcmBody"]')
        HERE^
```

Note that the parenthesis here are also important to get the desired `a` descendant of the parent.

Comment: Awesome! - that appears to work within the context - but now i have the problem that it's not filtering the [2] on the final result set. it looks like the result is //div[@class="rcmBody"]//a[2] instead of (//div[@class="rcmBody"]//a)[2]. Is that normal? Is there any way around that?

Comment: Scratch that - i found out it works like this:
$I->click('(.//a)[2]', '//div[@class="rcmBody"]')

Comment: @DAB `.//a[2]` means "select all `a`s that are descendants of the current node and that are the second `a` under their parent." `(.//a)[2]` means "select the second `a` descendant of the current node."